# In React how do I code split public pages (e.g. login) to separate them from secure pages?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I have a react application that has publicly accessible pages (login, forgot password etc) and secure pages (after a user has logged in). I want to use code splitting so that a user who doesn't login but accesses a publicly accessible page only gets the code for the public pages and not for the secure pages.

This is to reduce the size of the bundle the user needs to download initially and to ensure a user who never gets passed the login page can't see any code associated with a secure page.

I implemented code splitting for each route and this worked, but it meant every time a user went to a new page the user had to wait for the code for that page to load - this wasn't a great user experience. Instead, I want the code for all secure pages to be downloaded when the user has logged in successfully.

Is there a way of grouping the code together? Or grouping the routes together?

Answer (score 0):

in this case you'll need to create two application differently.

otherwise single page app build will ship all the files on any url load irrespective of what page user visits.

even if you group your code it doesn't matter as bundled js will be sent anyways.

splitting your single page to sub application would be better. you'll then just need to handle and serve accordingly.

and another option would be server side rendering give it shot if you are comfortable with it. [reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html)

Answer (score -1):

Can't you wrap your secure components in a container component And render the container based on the path, then inside download the code segments and render the secure components as needed?

```
<Switch>
   <Route path='/login' to{<Login />} />
   <Route path='/secure' to={<Secure />} />
</Switch>
```

Then inside of the  component, download the secure codebase and use another `<Switch />` inside of `<Secure />` to route to each secured page.